# css behave different in mozila and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

When i open my page, its navigation behaves different on chrome and Firefox, when I hover over it!

As stack-overflow do not allow me to post images(due to reputation<10) I have added images in  link below please review it and answer!

[image]

"CSS" of the navigation is:

```
#topnav{
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #33cc66;
    border: 2px solid #545453;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
}
#topnav a{
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid #545453;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #545453;*/
    color:#fff;
    float: left;
}
#topnav a:hover { background-color: #99e677;/*#b73b3b; */
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #545453;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or give us needed HTML? jsfiddle.net

Comment: paste your html too please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see - what you want is to change the background color on hover... so in your hover class remove:

```
padding-bottom: 3px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #545453;
```

Update your code to the following and I think you'll find it to work in all browsers.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/c9zPc/3/)**

```
#topnav{

    background-color: #33cc66;
    border: 2px solid #545453;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;   
}
#topnav a{
    padding: 0 12px;
    border-right: 2px solid #545453;
    color:#fff;
    float: left; 
}
#topnav a:hover { 
    background-color: #99e677;/*#b73b3b; */
}
```

**PS:** Very often, when your code renders differently in different in different browsers - that's a red light for you to stop and think: 'have I coded this correctly?'

Comment: Thank you very much! can you give me any hint what was my problem?

Comment: adding the padding and border on hover was causing the problem. You just need to change the background color